# Spring Batch accessing job parameter inside step

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a following Spring Batch Job config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .flow(stepA()).on("FAILED").to(stepC())
                .from(stepA()).on("*").to(stepB()).next(stepC())
                .end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepA() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepA").tasklet(new RandomFailTasket("stepA")).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepB() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepB").tasklet(new PrintTextTasklet("stepB")).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepC() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepC").tasklet(new PrintTextTasklet("stepC")).build();
    }

}
```

I'm starting the job with a following code:

```
    try {
                    Map<String,JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();
                    JobParameter ccReportIdParameter = new JobParameter("03061980");
                    parameters.put("ccReportId", ccReportIdParameter);

                    jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters(parameters));
                } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                        | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

How to access `ccReportId` parameter from job steps ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Tasklet.execute()` method takes parameter `ChunkContext`, where Spring Batch injects all the metadata. So you just need to dig into job parameters via these metadata structures:

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution()
      .getJobParameters().getString("ccReportId");
```

or other option is to access job parameters map this way:

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters().get("ccReportId");
```

but this gives you `Object` and you need to cast it to string.

Comment: And how can we access job parameter inside the custom ItemReader class ?