# accessing list of job parameters in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application as follows where I need to read two files daily and process:

```
MarketAFile_yyyy_mm_dd.csv
MarketBFile_yyyy_mm_dd.csv
```

I have configured `Job`  which first needs to fetch these files from the fileshare dynamically based on the date:

```
@Bean
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener())
            .start(getFiles())
            .next(step1())
            .build();
}


@Bean
public Step getFiles() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("getFiles")
            .tasklet(fileMovingTasklet)
            .build();
}
```

My `FileMovingTasklet` `execute()` method needs to access `jobParameters` which should be the name of the file (derived from enum `filename`) and the corresponding `previousWorkingDate` for that market. I am iterating over the list of markets as you can see below and want to dynamically set the filename and corresponding date as to build final filename for example:

```
MarketAFile_2018_02_15.csv
MarketBFile_2018_02_15.csv
```

How can I pass this final file name so I have it avaialble in `execute()` to perform a copy from fileshare to my local path?

```
@Component
public class FileMovingTasklet implements Tasklet, InitializingBean {


    @Value("${file.suffix}")
    private String suffix;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {


        try {
            //get files to look for, for all markets
            //copy from file share to local

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    private void copyFiles(...) {

        }

    }

}
```

Here is my Main entry point:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Autowired
    private PropertyHolder propertyHolder;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

        for (Market market : Market.values()) {

            List<MonthDay> listOfHolidays = propertyHolder.getHolidayMap(market);

            if (todayIsHoliday(listOfHolidays)) {
                String previousWorkingDay = getPreviousWorkingDay(listOfHolidays); //2018_02_15

            }
        }

//        JobParameters jobParameters = buildJobParameters();
//        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    }

    private JobParameters buildJobParameters() {
        Map<String, JobParameter> confMap = new HashMap<>();
        confMap.put(AS_OF_DATE, new JobParameter(new Date()));
        return new JobParameters(confMap);
    }
}
```

Enum class:

```
public enum Market {
    MARKETA("MarketA", "MarketAFile"),
    MARKETB("MarketA", "MarketBFile");  

   private final String market;
   private final String fileName;

   Market(String market, String filename) {
       this.market = market;
       this.fileName = filename;
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465142/spring-batch-accessing-job-parameter-inside-step

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: I used a Stringbuilder to append filenames separated by ; and then adding onto jobparmeter. With my approach it requires the file prefix to be set on enum Market

Answer (score 0):

Check [Spring Batch accessing job parameter inside step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465142/spring-batch-accessing-job-parameter-inside-step)

`//TODO read doco..`[See here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/context/ChunkContext.html#getStepContext--)